# I need to configure two select boxes and an input field with button

Tags: javascript, html

```js
            var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
    function submit() {
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            ol = document.getElementById("myList");
            li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
            for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    li[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    li[i].style.display = "none";

                }
            }
        }

        function changeInstitution(index) {
           if (index == 0) {
               ol = document.getElementById("myList");
               li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
               for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                   li[i].style.display = "";
               }
           }
           else {
               ol = document.getElementById("myList");
               li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
               for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                   a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                   if (a.href.indexOf('iobm') > -1) {
                       li[i].style.display = index == 1 ? "" : "none";
                   } else {
                       li[i].style.display = index == 1 ? "none" : "";
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       function changeYear(index) {
           if (index == 0) {
               ol = document.getElementById("myList");
               li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
               for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                   li[i].style.display = "";
               }
           }
           else {
               var selectedYear = index.options[index].value;
               ol = document.getElementById("myList");
               li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
               for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                   a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                   if (a.innerHTML.indexOf(selectedYear) > -1) {
                       li[i].style.display = "";
                   } else {
                       li[i].style.display = "none";
                   }
               }
           } 
       }
```

```css
div{
    margin: 50px;
  }
  #sear{
    margin-left: 150px
  }
  span{
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #0e0e0e;
  }
```

```html
<div id="sear" >
      <span>Filter results:&nbsp</span>
      <input type="text" id="myInput" name="search" placeholder="Search" style="padding: 5px">
      
      &nbsp  
      <select name="year" id="year" onchange="changeYear(this.selectedIndex);" style="padding: 5px">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option >2018</option>
        <option >2017</option>
        <option >2016</option>
        <option >2015</option>
        <option >2014</option>
        <option >2013</option>
        <option >2012</option>
        <option >2011</option>
        <option >2010</option>
      </select>
      &nbsp
      <select name="institution" id="institution" onchange="changeInstitution(this.selectedIndex);" style="padding: 5px">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option >IoBM</option>
        <option >Others</option>
      </select>
        &nbsp
      <button onclick="submit()"  style="padding: 5px">Search Results</button>
    

    </div>


    <div>
      <h3>Publications:</h3>
      <ol id="myList">
        <li id="2017"><a href="iobm">Dolore laborum consectetur in amet laborum irure dolor id sit adipisicing cillum est 2017.</a></li>
        <li id="2017"><a href="">Pariatur incididunt in occaecat consectetur elit velit tempor exercitation tempor aliqua 2017.</a></li>
        <li id="2016"><a href="">Velit nostrud duis dolore est mollit laborum non eiusmod mollit quis cillum qui id aliquip in in laborum cillum 2016.</a></li>
        <li id="2012"><a href="iobm">Aliqua sunt sed culpa consequat laborum laboris ut esse in consequat 2012. </a></li>
            <li id="2011"><a href="">Lorem ipsum in esse sed incididunt voluptate elit officia eu dolor duis minim nulla id 2011. </a></li>
        <li id="2011"><a href="">Dolore enim ad veniam cupidatat culpa aliquip voluptate adipisicing consequat anim pariatur in duis adipisicing 2011.</a></li>
        <li id="2010"><a href="iobm">Pariatur aute sit officia eu quis adipisicing laboris quis sed in id occaecat 2010.</a></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

So, guys, I need to configure two select boxes and an input field with a button, all the three elements have functions which iterate through the list and filter the desired results. 
But, there is a problem with the select boxes, they both override each other. And as their functions associated accept two parameters and cannot be configured with a button. 
What I simply want with my code is after a user inputs, and selects the options and then clicks the button, then only should the result display. That's all.

Would be so glad if you could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have effect only after the button is clicked, then I do not think you need to add onchange call on your dropdowns.

> The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been changed.

You should have one function for iterating and selecting your output binded to your button's onclick, which should work based on the selected values of the select boxes.

If you would like to have effect when the value in the select box changes, then you need to define an onchange method, too.

Edit:

So what I would change to make it work:

1. instead of using the a href to filter the list I would define probably name='instution_name' for every li
2. remove the onchange method and define a single submit method
3. in the submit method have something like (pseudo code):

Submit method:

```
function submit() {
    // Declare separate filter for year and institution
    var year_input,institution_input , year_filter, institution_filter, ul, li, a, i;
    year_input = document.getElementById('year');
    // this will hold the selected year e.g. 2018
    year_filter = year_input.value.toUpperCase();
    institution_input = document.getElementById('institution');
    // this will hold the selected institution
    institution_filter = institution_input.value.toUpperCase();
           ol = document.getElementById("myList");
           li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    // based on your html put the proper condition here
        if (li[i].id == year_filter && li[i].name == institution_filter)  {
        // show if both condition apply        
            li[i].style.display =  "" ;
        } else {
        //hide otherwise
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help but I have already done it but the list doesn't update.